# What is a "pipe" and how can it be "broken"?

Tags: ios, xcode, unix, pipe

[image]

I've gotten the "broken pipe" error from Xcode one time too many. I'm now curious to know exactly what a pipe is.

What is the concept of a "pipe" and how can it be "broken"?

Comment: A pipe is a long tube that holds a lot of data. If the receiving end of the pipe stops pulling the data out it starts backing up and the pipe bursts. The computer informs the end that's stuffing data into the pipe that this has happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pipe is simply an interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism used to connect the standard output of one process to the standard input of another.

An example is when you want to search a file for the word "pax":

```
cat filename | grep pax
```

and yes, I know you can `grep` the file directly but that doesn't explain how it works, does it?

This connects the standard output of the `cat` command to the standard input of the `grep` command. `cat` sends the contents of the file to its standard output, and `grep` reads its file (in this case) from its standard input. By connecting processes together like this, you can create your own tools consisting on any number of pipe segments. Things like:

```
show_users | grep pax | awk -F: '{print $4}' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | cut -c1-20
```

A *broken* pipe is one where (usually) the receiver of the data has closed the connection while the sender is still trying to send stuff through.

For example, if you send a large file through a pager program (to view it one page at a time):

```
cat myfile | pager
```

and then do a <kbd>CTRL-BREAK</kbd>, this may cause the `pager` process to shut down its input pipe before `cat` has finished using it. That's one possibility for getting this broken pipe.

---

From a cursory [Google search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=xcode+putpkt+broken+pipe), this particular problem seems to be related to ad hoc deployments and the solutions given usually include exiting most of your software and rebooting most of your devices.

This is probably serious enough to report the issue to Apple. The more developers who complain about it, the more likely something will be done to fix it.

Comment: So what is a "broken" pipe?

Comment: `pr -e4 -n ten-thousand-lines.c | sed 10q` ends up with a broken pipe.  Whether `pr` bothers to tell you that it got the SIGPIPE signal is another matter; it may well simply exit as a result of the signal (generating a non-zero exit status).

Comment: Pipes do *not* necessarily connect the "standard" input and output. It's possible programmatically to pass any I/O through a pipe, though from the command line you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The `|` character is often called a pipe. In the various UNIX shells (that I know of) it can be used to pipe the output of one command to the input of another.

```
cat myfile.txt | head
```

The `head` command only shows the first few lines of its input. At that point, it closes its input. This poses a problem for the command that was generating the input. Where does it write to? Whenever we have this situation, or the situation when the writing process ends before the reader is through, it's called a "broken pipe".

To prevent the `cat` command from lingering forever, the UNIX standard defines a special signal ([SIGPIPE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_10.html#tag_02_10_14), [signal 13](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?signal.h+3)) which it send to `cat`. The default action for this signal is to kill the process, which makes the `cat` end nicely.

It looks like the application you're using has installed a signal handler for all signals, including SIGPIPE, which creates the little popup message that you see.

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to come up fairly often. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490366/ad-hoc-deployment-issue-putpkt-write-failed-broken-pipe
it's "...an internal error in Xcode's ability to talk to your phone. It doesn't mean you've done anything wrong, it's a bug in the development system"

Answer (score 1):

A pipe is an IPC mechanism on Unix systems. A pipe has two ends, a read end, and a write end. Data that is written into the write end can be read from the read end and comes out in the order in which it was written.

In the Unix command line world, pipes are a very common way of hooking programs together to get a job done. For example `sed 's/foo/bar/g' fred.txt | grep -e 'bar.*baz'` will read in the file `fred.txt` replace all instances of the string `foo` with the string `bar` then search the result for lines that contain `bar` followed by some number of characters, then `baz`.

That, of course, doesn't seem terribly useful. But I'm sure if you think about it that you can see how you might be able to put that to all kinds of interesting uses, especially once you have programs like `awk` or `perl` at your disposal.

The pipe system has been a part of Unix from very early on. And if a process in your pipeline exits you usually want all the programs in the pipeline to exit. This means that, by default, a process that writes into a pipe were the process on the read end is gone will get a `SIGPIPE` signal. And if its blocked that signal, the `write` will still fail with a special kind of error indicating that the pipe has 'broken'.

The default handling of `SIGPIPE` kills the process that receives it. And if it isn't the 'head' of the pipeline, the whole `SIGPIPE` thing propagates back up the chain.

What Xcode is complaining about is that it started some sub-program to do something with a pipe leading to it, and that sub-program died unexpectedly leaving the pipe broken..

Answer (score 0):

A “broken” pipe is one where one end has been `close()`'d and the other is being read from or written to.  For example, in the following shell command:

```
cat foo | less
```

The `cat` process holds the writing end of the pipe, and the `less` process the reading one.  If the reader process closes the pipe, the pipe is broken (and therefore useless); the writer process will receive the “broken pipe” error from the operating system.

Comment: Actually, it's only "broken" if the reader closes it. If the writer closes it (as `cat` obviously will as soon as it's finished), the reader will just see a normal end-of-file.

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely correct... I'll update my answer.